# /api/rest returns not found in magento rest services

Tags: magento, rest

i need to know how to allow a guest user to get some data from using rest method in magento. I have created and followed all roles and users creation according to magento commerce website.
can anybody please help me by pointing out the steps clearly to get product details from a magento site  to a guest using myhost/api/rest/products thank you verymuch in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your using ubuntu you have to do the following,

1.Goto etc-apache2-apache2.conf and enable write mod to the file and make a backup.Then edit the original file as follows

`<Directory />
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from all
 </Directory>`

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>                                         
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
 </Directory>
```

2.Enable mode rewrite from terminal using

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart apache and try the products url, If your using windows google how to do the same in windows.